# Locked Away- What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> A sewer cover is my cousin, we share many traits
>
> People who have me, often lock me away
>
> I am two-faced but bare only one
>
> People do anything to get me, sometimes using a gun
>
> I have the most power when given away
>
> And I am often on display

Hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be

> a coin?

*A sewer cover is my cousin, we share many traits*

> They're both flat and metal, roughly the same shape.

*People who have me, often lock me away*

> Misers hiding money away in their houses, or locking money in a safe.

*I am two-faced but bare only one*

> A coin has two sides, but usually only one bears a bare face.

*People do anything to get me, sometimes using a gun*

> Bank robbery.

*I have the most power when given away*

> Money doesn't have much power in itself, unless it can be spent on something.

(Thanks @LifelongScholar for help with this clue!)

*And I am often on display*

> Maybe in a coin collector's album.

Comment: My first thought as well

Comment: Definitely what popped into my head as well.

Comment: Even I think it's coin but it's not 'charity', it's exercising its value by spending it. After all, that's the only way to yield it's 'most power'. Just saying, rest's good.

Answer (score 8):

You are-

> **A medal**

A sewer cover is my cousin, we share many traits

> They're both flat and metal, roughly the same shape.

People who have me, often lock me away

> Locking medals to keep them safe- even in display cases when they are displayed.

I am two-faced but bare only one

> Only one face of a medal is seen when it is displayed or awarded.

People do anything to get me, sometimes using a gun

> Tournaments- although perhaps not "anything", but yes sometimes even breaking laws to win.

I have the most power when given away

> A medal has the most value or meaning when being awarded.

And I am often on display

> Often, medals are displayed prominently- like in display cases

Comment: +1 Not exactly what I was thinking of, but a good alternate answer!